# Generate a SQL script from Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, swing, hibernate, p6spy

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5-Final for my Java Swing application and I do many `UDPATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` with it (in HQL or with `Criteria`).

Now, what I'm trying to do is to export a SQL script of all modifications done on my database but I don't know how to do that. This script need to contain only the modifications (and not the creation of the tables) and put them on a `.sql` file (exported file path will be chosen by the user)

Do you have any ideas that can solve my problem ?

Thank you in advance !

[Edit] : Some forums talk about `p6spy`, can it answer to my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p6spy` should help here.

In general, following should do the job for you:

1. enable `p6spy` in your app (see official docs: http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/)

afterwards you have basically 2 options:

1. use provided: [`BatchFileLogger`](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/p6spy/engine/spy/appender/BatchFileLogger.java), enabling it via: `appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.BatchFileLogger` in `spy.properties` (it's however undocumented yet, see: https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/issues/119)

**OR**

1. implement custom `com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.MessageFormattingStrategy`, that would be returning sql only (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23521623/1581069 for idea on implementation) and configure it in `spy.properties` via: `logMessageFormat=FooFormat`
2. set `sqlexpression` to match the queries you need - restricting `CREATE/ALTER/... TABLE/SEQUENCE/...` (see official docs: http://p6spy.github.io/p6spy/2.0/configandusage.html)

still there are some tricky points, like:

- `databaseDialectDateFormat` property (to be able to kind of replay the output without modifications). For inspiration for some of the common databases, see the unit tests of p6spy itself: https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/tree/master/src/test/resources/com/p6spy/engine/spy

Comment: Thank you for your help, so I'll try `p6spy`.

Also, i forget a point, my application is "multi-dialect", that means I let the user choose between `Oracle SQL`, `MS SQL Server 2005` or `MS SQL Server 2005` (on the login screen). So how can I dynamically set the `realdriver` ?

Comment: well, it depends, if you're using jdbc4 drivers + would use jdbc url proxing (for Oracle, something like: `jdbc:p6spy:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE`) => no need to configure `realdriver` at all. Still it depends if you use some app server,... feel free to ask for more details on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/p6spy-users

Comment: btw. property: `realdriver` has been deprecated in favor of: `driverlist` (still some docs might be outdated)

Comment: So I did as you suggested with your second solution (I created a class implementing the `MessageFormattingStrategy`). Now I will try to filter only `UDPATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` sqlexpression but I think the most of the work is done now ! Thank you a thousand times !

Comment: I'm almost done with my problem. I've filtered my SQL `.log` with `filter=true` and `sqlexpression=^(update|insert|delete).*$` in the `spy.properties` but there is a little issue : values are not escaped. So if the user put a field to `This is a test '`, the script will be `update MYTABLE set  field='This is a test '' where id=1;` and it won't work because of the unescaped `'`. Is there a solution ?

Comment: Seems like a bug in p6spy. Please file a [new one](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/issues), as related test has no such scenario considered yet: https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/blob/master/src/test/java/com/p6spy/engine/spy/LoggedSQLValidTest.java