# Get or create insert statment from entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, insert

there is the possibility of existing entity class with values generate an insert statment?

EDIT:
I mean to generate an insert statement for an instance of an entity class, to execute that statement separately.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question making no sense to me.

Comment: please ask the question more aptly....

Comment: Check out JPA/Hibernate..

Comment: Do you mean to generate an insert statement for an _instance_ of an entity class, to execute that statement separately?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I mean :)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23651482/785663

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [Fastnate](http://fastnate.org) you can create SQL statements for entities without a connection to a database:

```
public String createSQL() {
    // Create your entity
    TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
    entity.setSomeProperty("Example");
    ...

    // Write your entity as SQL
    StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
    EntitySqlGenerator sqlGenerator = new EntitySqlGenerator(result);
    sqlGenerator.write(entity);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please how do I exclude the generator from adding the primary key column to the generated SQL string. This is because my table has an id with auto generated column.

Comment: @Uchenna, could you create a separate question for this (and only add a reference here)?

Comment: Fastnate looks promising, but it doesn't yet seem to handle EmbeddedIds. There's an issue tracking it in the Github project, but it appears to keep getting postponed from release to release. Is support for EmbeddedId fields imminent, or should we consider another solution?

Comment: I think that you should ask that question on the issue page. How should we know that there is the demand for an issue, if no one asks for it?